# A mutant riddle

Tags: riddle

> If its name is true it's a mutant
>   
> Of one of up high and one down low
>   
> At home in sky and sea
>   
> Split in half and separated by a million miles
>   
> Yet combined to make one which cannot drown
>
> What am I?

Comment: Dang the wording of that first line.  I can't even get to the second because all I can think of is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--szrOHtR6U

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I had no intention of that! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a

> [Sunfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunfish). Here's a cool picture of a type of Sunfish, the Basking Shark:
>
>
>  [image: Basking Shark]
>
>
>  or it could be a [Starfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfish). Here's a cool picture of a Starfish:
>
>
>  [image]

Comment: YOU'RE SO CLOSE! when I say up high I mean REALLY up high...

Comment: I could cry you're so close... Sun is another name for what im thinking of

Comment: You must get it now... Its not really a type of fish as such

Comment: YES! YOU GOT IT!

Comment: If it doesn't have a tail, it's not a starfish....I'm done...